# Is it possible to add each value of ngFor as one value?

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

There are some values returned by ngFor in Total Column. Now I wanted to add those value to get a one grandTotal. I didn't get the idea. Anyone can help me??

In below second table:

I want {{sales.Total}} values to be added and return grand total.

/*****First Table*****/

```
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">S.N</th>
                        <th scope="col">Items</th>
                        <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                        <th scope="col">Rate</th>
                        <th scope="col">Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let sales of salesTransaction, let i = index">
                            <th>{{i+1}}</th>
                            <!-- <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let salesTransaction">{{salesTransaction.ProductName}}</td> -->
                            <td>{{sales.ProductName}}</td>
                            <td>{{sales.Quantity}}</td>
                            <td>{{sales.Rate}}</td>
                            <td>{{sales.Total}}</td>
                        </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

/*****Second Table*****/

```
            <table class="right-table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Sub-Total</th>
                            <td *ngFor="let sales of salesTransaction">{{sales.Total}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <hr class="divider">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Tax</th>
                            <td>Happy</td>
                    </tr>
                    <hr class="divider">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Grand Total</th>
                            <td>0000</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a method that returns grand total

```
   getGrandTotal(): number {
        return this.salesTransaction.reduce((acc, val) => acc += val.Total, 0);
      }

<tr>
  <th>Grand Total</th>
   <td>{{getGrandTotal()}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table class="right-table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Sub-Total</th>
                            <td *ngFor="let sales of salesTransaction">{{sales.Total}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <hr class="divider">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Tax</th>
                            <td>Happy</td>
                    </tr>
                    <hr class="divider">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Grand Total</th>
                            <td>{{salesTransaction.reduce((total, value) => total += value.Total, 0)}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: umm..i Get it now... I solved the problem. :) Thank you.

Comment: wc! If there are any changes then let me know and edit the answer

Comment: sure... I will :)